# how to sort object in array based on price

Tags: javascript

if I have something like this:

```
var lowestPricesCars =
{
  HondaC:
  {
    owner: "",
    price: 45156
  },
  FordNew:
  {
    owner: "",
    price:4100
  },
  HondaOld:
  {
    owner: "",
    price: 45745
  },
  FordOld:
  {
    owner: "",
    price: 34156
  },
}
```

How can I order the cars based on price ?

Please if the question is not clear then comment it out.

Thanks

Comment: `lowestPricesCars` is an object with cars sorted by the order that they are inserted into `lowestPricesCars`. Consistent, value based sorting is best done via arrays rather than objects - would you like to see an example of this?

Comment: @DacreDenny thanks for the suggestion. But I have built my code already using an object. Changing it to an array will be too much work. Is there a quick way to change it to array and order it and then return back to object ?

Comment: *" to array then back to object"* . Still not reliable with regard to order. Will need to change your code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(lowestPricesCars)
const keysSortedByPrice = arrayOfKeys.sort((a,b) => {
  return lowestPricesCars[a].price - lowestPricesCars[b].price;
});
let carsSortedByPrice = {}
keysSortedByPrice.forEach(key => carsSortedByPrice[key] = lowestPricesCars[key])
```

If you want to reverse the order:

```
return lowestPricesCars[b].price - lowestPricesCars[a].price;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a concise way via **ES6** [**`Object.entries`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [**`Array.sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [**`Array.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

However object's key order is **not guaranteed** and not consistent between browsers and it is not recommended to be used.

```js
const data = { HondaC: { owner: "", price: 45156 }, FordNew: { owner: "", price:4100 }, HondaOld: { owner: "", price: 45745 }, FordOld: { owner: "", price: 34156 } }

console.log(Object.entries(data)
  .sort((a,b) => a[1].price - b[1].price)  // for DESC b[1].price - a[1].price
  .reduce((r,[k,v]) => (r[k] = v, r), {}))
```